# How to fetch data from SCD type2 table for particular year

Tags: sql, reporting, etl, business-intelligence

I have one scd type 2 table , which contains :-

```
ib  address start date  end date  flag
1   a        Jan-12     Dec-00    X
2   b        Jan-13     13-Mar    x
2   c        13-Mar     Dec-00    y
3   d        Feb-13     Dec-00    Y
1   v        Sep-17     Dec-00    Y
```

I want to fetch all the employee's address  for year 2013.
select all the active  records from the table for year 2013.

Comment: How do you identify an employee? specify the data types and post your attempt at solving this.

Comment: What is the data type of `start date` and `end date`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to retrieve two sets of data:

- employees addresses valid from anytime in the past, until 2013 or later (start date < 2013 and end date >= 2013)
- employees addresses with validity starting in 2013.

This gives you the whole dataset of addresses which have been valid in 2013. You may have more than one address per employee, so you need to include the validity dates in your select statement.

Assuming the table is called `addresses`, and the date columns are properly formatted:

```
select *
from addresses
where
    -- addresses valid until 2013 or later
    (year(start_date) < 2013 and year(end_date) >= 2013)
    -- addresses  which started being valid in 2013
    OR (year(start_date) = 2013)
```